# Firebase Storage Error: An unknown error has occurred

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I using `react-native-image-picker` for image selection tool to get the file path for `putFile()` function. But get an error `Error: An unknown error has occurred.` after I selected the image while uploading.

```
ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

  if (response.didCancel) {
    console.log('User cancelled image picker');
  }
  else if (response.error) {
    console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
  }
  else if (response.customButton) {
    console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
  }
  else {
    firebase.storage().ref("123.jpg").putFile(response.path).then((success) =>{
      console.log(success);
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
});
```

The response json from picker :

```
{
  "height": 464,
  "width": 825,
  "type": "image/jpeg",
  "fileName": "deadpool-2-domino-cable.jpg",
  "fileSize": 114189,
  "path": "/storage/emulated/0/Download/deadpool-2-domino-cable.jpg",
  "data": "thisisbase64string",
  "uri": "content://media/external/images/media/301465",
  "isVertical": true,
  "originalRotation": 0
}
```

**`react-native : 0.55.1`
`react-native-firebase : ^4.0.7`**